# Difference between MBean and MXBean

Tags: java, jmx, mbeans

I have the following questions regarding **MBean** and **MXBean**:

1. What is the difference between *MBean* and *MXBean*?
2. What are the use cases for *MBean* and  *MXBean*?

Comment: this article have some diferences https://weblogs.java.net/blog/emcmanus/archive/2006/02/what_is_an_mxbe.html

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`MXBean`s are just a special kind of `MBean`s. The main difference is that `MXBean` restrict the data types, so that they are "more compatible" with potential clients.

As example: a `MBean` can expose attributes of a data type `Foo`. Now the client also needs to have this type `Foo` to make sense of the attribute.

The `MXBean` tries to restrict the data types to those "already available" - `java.lang.*` etc.

See [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/mbeans/mxbeans.html)

Answer (score 15):

An MXBean is an MBean which is constrained to open types, basically primitive types, Strings and compositions thereof. Due to these constraints, an MXBean can get used without class loading and that makes them interoperable even with non-Java clients. You can find the specification here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/management/package-summary.html#package_description

Answer (score 4):

`MBeans` can be any of java objects, in which we can store/retrive `Serializable/Externalizable` objects using methods. Based on the design pattern used in objects, we can differentiate either Standard(static) or Dynamic. Recommended to maintain Interface class name suffixed with MBean

`MXBeans` reference only a pre-defined set of types. Recommended to maintain Interface class name suffixed with `MXBean`. Implements interface of Dynamic or cusotmized `JavaBean`. Using MXBean, We can facilitate any client to use MBeans.

Refer [MBean vs MXBean](http://www.javafundu.com/2009/12/mbean-vs-mxbean.html)

Answer (score 4):

**MBeans :**

Can be any of java objects, in which we can store/retrive Serializable/Externalizable objects using methods.

Based on the design pattern used in objects, we can differentiate either Standard(static) or Dynamic. Recommended to maintain Interface class name suffixed with MBean.

**MXBeans :**

reference only a pre-defined set of types. Recommended to maintain Interface class name suffixed with MXBean. Implements interface of Dynamic or customized JavaBean.

Using MXBean, We can facilitate any client to use MBeans. Additional details required to use MXBean.

[Refer Here](http://www.javafundu.com/2009/12/mbean-vs-mxbean.html)